# Need to diaplay a blinking icon for GPS status on top of my application

Tags: android, gps

I need to display an icon in my application that blinks exactly like the default GPS icon in the phone. When the GPS is disconnected and searching for GPS ,the default GPS icon blinks and when it is connected the default GPS icon is static. I need to implement this functionality of the phone to an icon displayed in the top of my application. I am able to get the first fix of the GPS and is able to make the animation of the icon to static. How can I know the when the GPS is again lost and then again connected.

Please help me with your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance.
Sundeep.S.

Comment: Please accept answers to your questions with the tick-mark to the left of the answer. It will help future users know that an answer works, and will reward the author.

Answer (score 0):

In your code Listen to [GpsStatus.Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html). For example

```
GpsStatus.Listener listener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {
    void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        if (event == GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS) {
           // Do tasks
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me how to check whether the GPS connection has lost after the first fix and how to check the connection comes back after some time. I am not able to find a solution for this.

Comment: @Sundeep go the link there are some flags like GPS_EVENT_STARTED and stopped. I thiink it should work although I don't have direct experience with that

Answer (score 0):

this may help you... implement following code.

```
public void turnGPSOn()
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
         intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
         this.sendBroadcast(intent);

        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
            final Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
            myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            myIntent.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            this.sendBroadcast(myIntent);
        }

    }
```

Comment: through this code you can programmatic turn on GPS. however GPS is enabled a GPS icon start blinking.

Comment: Explaining, means the algorithm. What will the major lines do here, what will they request from system etc. Can you explain that?